# mysql database shows question mark instead of japanese text

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a mysql database which consists of tables `job`, `steps` and `company`.

company table:

```
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field              | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id                 | varchar(45)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| prefecture_id      | varchar(2)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| industry_id        | varchar(2)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| offset             | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| pid                | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| name               | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| email              | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| tel                | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| fax                | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| address            | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| address_coordinate | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| url                | varchar(511) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| image_url          | varchar(511) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| flexible_1         | varchar(511) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| flexible_2         | varchar(511) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| flexible_3         | varchar(511) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| flexible_4         | varchar(511) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| flexible_5         | varchar(511) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| flexible_6         | varchar(511) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| flexible_7         | varchar(511) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| flexible_8         | varchar(511) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| flexible_9         | varchar(511) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| flexible_10        | varchar(511) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| sequence           | varchar(511) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| del_flg            | char(1)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| create_date        | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| create_user        | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| update_date        | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| update_user        | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I'm trying to save data which consists Japanese text from this code;

```
public function getDetail($prefectureId,$pid,$offset,$industryId,$companyId,$entryName,$priority,$searchNum) 
{

    $result = $this->itpApi->getCompany($prefectureId,$pid,$offset,$industryId,$companyId,$entryName,$priority,$searchNum);
    $itpCompanyDetail = $this->itpApi->getReturnArray();

    $this->db->insert('company',$itpCompanyDetail);
}
```

and this is the code where I fetch the data;

```
protected function execApihtmlParser($companyId,$opt,$prefectureId,$pid,$offset,$industryId,$slp=1) {
    $curl = curl_init();

    sleep($slp);
    curl_setopt_array($curl, $opt);

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

    if ($err) {
        $this->errMsg = "cURL Error #:" . $err;

        return false;
    } else {
        $response = mb_convert_encoding($response, 'UTF8', 'ASCII,JIS,UTF-8,EUC-JP,SJIS-WIN');

        $xml = simplexml_load_string($response);

        $html = new simple_html_dom();
        $html->load($xml->retdata);

        $item = array();
        foreach($html->find('body') as $home) {
        //populate all items
                $item['id'] = $companyId;
                $item['prefecture_id'] = $prefectureId;
                $item['industry_id'] = $industryId;
                $item['offset'] = $offset;
                $item['pid'] = $pid;
                $item['name'] = str_replace("\r\n",'',trim($home->find('div[id="home"] div[id="topinfo"] h1[id="basetop"]', 0)->plaintext));
                $item['email'] = preg_replace("/\s+/u",'',trim($home->find('div[id="home"] div[id="mainblock"] div[class="txtblock"]', 8)->plaintext));
                $item['tel'] = preg_replace("/\s+/u",'',trim($home->find('div[id="home"] div[id="topinfo"] p', 2)->plaintext));
                $item['fax'] = preg_replace("/\s+/u",'',trim($home->find('div[id="home"] div[id="mainblock"] div[class="txtblock"] p', 3)->plaintext));
                $item['address'] = str_replace("\r\n",'',trim($home->find('div[id="home"] div[id="mainblock"] div[class="txtblock"] p', 4)->plaintext));
                $item['address_coordinate'] = str_replace("\r\n",'',trim($home->find('div[id="home"] div[id="mainblock"] div[class="txtblock"] p', 4)->plaintext));
                $item['url'] = preg_replace("/\s+/u",'',trim($home->find('div[id="mainblock"] div[class="txtblock"]', 7)->plaintext));
                $item['image_url'] = str_replace("\r\n",'',trim($home->find('div[id="home"] div[id="shopintro"] p img', 0)->src));
                $item['flexible_1'] = preg_replace("/\s+/u",'',trim($home->find('div[id="home"] div[id="mainblock"] div[class="txtblock"] p', 1)->plaintext));
                $item['flexible_2'] = preg_replace("/\s+/u",'',trim($home->find('div[id="home"] div[id="mainblock"] div[class="txtblock"] p', 5)->plaintext));
                $item['flexible_3'] = preg_replace("/\s+/u",'',trim($home->find('div[id="home"] div[id="mainblock"] div[class="txtblock"] p', 6)->plaintext));
                $item['flexible_4'] = preg_replace("/\s+/u",'',trim($home->find('div[id="home"] div[id="mainblock"] div[class="txtblock"]', 11)->plaintext));
                $item['flexible_5'] = preg_replace("/\s+/u",'',trim($home->find('div[id="category"] div[id="mainblock"] div[class="txtblock"]', 0)->plaintext));
                $item['flexible_6'] = preg_replace("/\s+/u",'',trim($home->find('div[id="category"] div[id="mainblock"] div[class="txtblock"]', 1)->plaintext));
                $item['flexible_7'] = preg_replace("/\s+/u",'',trim($home->find('div[id="category"] div[id="mainblock"] div[class="txtblock"]', 2)->plaintext));
                $item['flexible_8'] = preg_replace("/\s+/u",'',trim($home->find('div[id="category"] div[id="mainblock"] div[class="txtblock"]', 3)->plaintext));
                $item['flexible_9'] = preg_replace("/\s+/u",'',trim($home->find('div[id="category"] div[id="mainblock"] div[class="txtblock"]', 4)->plaintext));
                $item['flexible_10'] = preg_replace("/\s+/u",'',trim($home->find('div[id="category"] div[id="mainblock"] div[class="txtblock"] p', 5)->plaintext));
        }

        $items = array();
        $items = $item;

        // When parsing fails, processing ends
        if ($items === NULL) {
            $this->errMsg = "Parse error: syntax error.";
            return false;
        }

        $this->returnArray = $items;
        return true;
    }
}
```

After I check the database table `company`, it has '??????' question marks inserted. Like this;

```
| KN0100060500041981 | 01            | 1           |    400 | 11178 | ??????? |       | 011-512-5351 | 064-0807??????????????????? | ?????                    | ?????                    | ??????????????                       |                                           | ????????   | ??????    | ?????         | ???????????????         | ????????              |  ???????       | ????????      | ???????????    | ???????       | ??????? | NULL     | NULL    | NULL        | NULL        | NULL        | NULL        |
```

**NOTES:**
I just found this.

I checked the database setting via command line;

using `SHOW CREATE TABLE company;` this is the result;

```
| company | CREATE TABLE `company` (
  `id` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `prefecture_id` varchar(2) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `industry_id` varchar(2) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `offset` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pid` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `tel` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `fax` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `address` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `address_coordinate` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `url` varchar(511) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_url` varchar(511) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `flexible_1` varchar(511) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `flexible_2` varchar(511) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `flexible_3` varchar(511) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `flexible_4` varchar(511) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `flexible_5` varchar(511) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `flexible_6` varchar(511) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `flexible_7` varchar(511) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `flexible_8` varchar(511) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `flexible_9` varchar(511) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `flexible_10` varchar(511) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `sequence` varchar(511) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `del_flg` char(1) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `create_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `create_user` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `update_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `update_user` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`prefecture_id`,`industry_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
```

**UPDATE**

As I reviewed and based from online manuals, I mark the FINAL ANSWER below.

Comment: Have you set the correct character encoding for your DB table? `phpmyadmin` >> _your table_ >> Operations >> Collation

Comment: Does your database use a collation that supports those japanese characters?

Comment: I did this command line; `ALTER DATABASE dbname CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;` then `ALTER TABLE tablename CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the character set to be different to support the Japanese character sets. The character sets affect the storage and the communication between the server and the client software.

to use unicode you can do this:

```
SET NAMES 'utf8';
```

Character sets can be specified for the database level.
 e.g.

```
CREATE DATABASE mydb
    DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8
    DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

And also per table.

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_name (column_list)
    [[DEFAULT] CHARACTER SET charset_name]
    [COLLATE collation_name]]

ALTER TABLE tbl_name
    [[DEFAULT] CHARACTER SET charset_name]
    [COLLATE collation_name]
```

Answer (score 0):

To save language other then English your table should have Character Set UTF-8.Please Make sure you have Character Set UTF-8 for your table.

Answer (score 0):

Just found the answer, Here it is;

```
ALTER TABLE tablename CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```